# Swipe anywhere on screen Android

Tags: android, view, touch, swipe

I'm using the setOnTouchlistner class for detecting left and right swipes. I can get it to work fine on a listview, but the listview is too small to get a good swipe every time.

I then tried to set the swipe to the main LinearLayout. I have three other LinearLayout inside this. But it is not working thanks for any help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/driveView"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Here is the code:

```
private LinearLayout myView = null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drive);
myView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.driveView);

myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            showdrivedialog(mContext, "Drive List", "Change to Ascending list!");
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
              showdrivedialog(mContext, "Drive List", "Change to Descending list!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: If this view has child views with touch listener you need to return false on them so this view can get the touch

Comment: None of the other views have touch listener, I have onClickListner, onFocusChangeListner, onEditorActionListner and OnItemClickListner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two matters I want to mention.

1)  I don't know about OnSwipeTouchListener but I got interested. I suspect `android:clickable="true"` should be false because there seems to be a conflict between swiping and clicking.

2)  Look at this SO link @ [How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures). I don't know where you got the **OnSwipeTouchListener** class but you can copy the one with 274 votes!

Personally I did not use this class. I have used and extended **HorizontalScrollView**.

Comment: I did try with clickable set to false, but on another post someone got it to work by setting it to true. That is the same OnSwipeTouchListener.